# Which version of .Net Standard should be targeted in a class library that supports a UAP Ver 10 application

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard

I have a game that I programmed using C#/MonoGame. I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 and am targeting release in the Windows App Store. I am planning on having 2 versions of game, one in the Windows App Store and one that does not run on UWP (so can be installed on non Windows 10 machines).

- The UWP application is targeting Windows 10 Anniversary Edition
  (10.0; Build 14393).
- The Non UWP application is targeting .Net
  Framework 4.6.2. (I don't need to target this version though. I think
  .Net Framework 4.5 or newer would be fine).
- The class library is using .NetStandard Version 1.5.

**Error Message**
'XXX.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v1.5'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586'.

So, I'm having trouble figuring out which version of .Net Standard I need to target in my class library to support UAP ver 10. I'm new to .Net Standard, so the answer is probably simple.

Comment: Turn it around: what is the highest standard your library actually needs? When it works with 1.1, no reason to go higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer on the [.Net Standard GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md). The last supported version in UWP is **.NET Standard 1.4**, the next version to be implemented is **.NET Standard 2.0** which won't be available before the Fall Creators Update (so after the summer) as mentioned at Build 2017.

Comment: Thank you, I just switched to .NET Standard 1.4 and the compiler is happier. What does it mean when I see vNext in the .Net Standard chart?

Comment: That they are considering compatibility in a future release of that version. But at Build they said they next version for UWP will be 2.0.